# String index out of range on button pressed

Tags: java

Having problems with a little hangman game I'm making.

```
private void btnTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                     
    btnT.setEnabled(false);          
    if(word.charAt(0)=='t'){
        lblSpace1.setText("T");
    }
    if(word.charAt(1)=='t'){
        lblSpace2.setText("T");
    }
    if(word.charAt(2)=='t'){
        lblSpace3.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(3)=='t'){
        lblSpace4.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(4)=='t'){
        lblSpace5.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(5)=='t'){
        lblSpace6.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(6)=='t'){
        lblSpace7.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(7)=='t'){
        lblSpace8.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(8)=='t'){
        lblSpace9.setText("T");
    }        
    if(word.charAt(9)=='t'){
        lblSpace10.setText("T");
    }
    if(!word.contains("t")){
        guessesLeft--;
        lblGuessesleft.setText("Number: "+guessesLeft+"");            
    }
}
```

The code checks if the letter `t` is in each space of the word. However, some words aren't 10 characters long, so the error "String index out of range" is printed.

Is there a way to only check the the letters that are in `word`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about [for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Can you give us more information? What is `lblSpace10`?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I posted my answer. I feel it is shabby too. I do not know why? glad to hear your input thank you

Comment: @KickButtowski My first concern would be with the use of Lambda functions, the poor OP doesn't seem to have an understanding of arrays, let alone collections, that might just be too far over there head - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh k but it just another flavor. do you have any ohter concerns?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I could easily copy other answers but I wanted to have new answer even though I totally agree with u

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm not saying it's a bit solution, but it is an advance solution ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank u and someone voted me down :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)

        if(word.charAt(i) == 't')//if this condition is true
        {                  //that means the character is at the position `i`
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    lblSpace1.setText("T");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // do other stuff
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

You cannot have problems of type `IndexOutOfRange` with this code.

Comment: Ah, this will cut down on unnecessary code quite significantly. However, this isn't finding at what position the letter 't' appears in the word? The clunky code I used in the question does this.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand. How can I get it to tell me the position of the character?

Comment: @L0glamb i is the index that you can have access to char of string by using charAt(i)

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to read more into some basic data structures like arrays as well as basic `for` and `while` loops. This will help you immensely while working on your game.

Here's an idea of where to start:

```
int word_length = word.length();
char input = 't'; //instead of hard coding t, try getting the user input from somewhere


for( int i=0; i< word_length; i++ )
{
    if( word.charAt(i) == input )
    {
        //do stuff with labels
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Another Flavor that you may wanna take a look at is** 
In `Java 8` you can do this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String s = "TTTTT";
       List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(""));
       list.stream()
           .filter( st -> st.equals("T"))
           .forEach(st -> System.out.println(" I am T"));

   IntStream.range(0, list.size())
             .filter(index -> list.get(index).equals("T"))
             .forEach(index -> System.out.println("The poistion is " + index));
}
```

Output:

```
 I am T
 I am T
 I am T
 I am T
 I am T
The poistion is 0
The poistion is 1
The poistion is 2
The poistion is 3
The poistion is 4
```

**Explantion**:

String s is converted to a list by using split and regex "", and list uses stream class that has filter which acts like if clause, and if string st is equal to T; for each which is a for loop System.out I am T in out put or you can whatever you desire to do.

Second answer is like for loop so you can have access to index and its item

Comment: A stream-based solution would be a nice "advanced" answer, @Kick Buttowski. It looks like your filter is incorrect and it looks like the `lblSpace*` variables need the position of the filter to act.

Comment: @JanNielsen thank you. what is wrong with my filter? could you be more clear? cuz It runs perfectly in my laptop thank you again

Comment: @JanNielsen in my second answer OP can access to the index and its item as well.